# How can I add elements to an ArrayList at even or odd positions?

Tags: java

I have two methods that populate one ArrayList and I want one of the methods to add elements at even positions while the other adds elements in odd positions, so that I get  an interleaved list of data.

How can I add elements in even or odd positions?

```
for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {
     myList.add( ,mData.get(i))
{
```

**Clarification. I don't need a list of even or odd numbers I need to get the next even or odd number from my variable `i` in the for loop. ie for `i` to `mdata.size()` store elements only in even places even if it exceeded the size of `mData` which it will**

Comment: Do you want a list of interleaved elements ie myList should contain interleaved elements or u want to store the interleave elements from mData in a myList?

Answer (score 1):

`if(i % 2) == 0` then `i` is even. Otherwise, `i` is odd.

The `%` operator returns the remainder of two numbers, for example:

`5 % 2` is 1, but `4 % 2` is 0.

Modulo can be slow, in your case `i` is integer, so you can do:

```
if (x & 1 == 0) {
   Even
}
```

Comment: I have added clarification to my original post. please take a look

Comment: I don't really understand it, can you explain it a little bet more please?

Answer (score 1):

`Lists` are structures with dynamic allocated size so it's hard to place exactly at odd or even position. You add element, size is 1, add second, size is 2 etc.
**But** you can add elements to List in specific order with "synchronized" methods. One method will start first and will add elements at positions 0, 2, 4 etc. while second method at 1, 3, 5 etc.

But i don't think that `List` is proper structure. If you want to add items exactly to odd or even positions, choose structure with fixed size i.e. classic array, fill up array and then you can convert it to dynamic List(if you need to pass / send done List somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this
using modulo operator

```
  if (i % 2 != 0)
        { 



        }
```

Comment: I have added clarification to my original post. please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Use the folowing code could be better:

```
    public static boolean isEven(int i) {
    return (i & 1) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This shure launch a ConcurrentModificationException, you cannot modify a List (except it is a synchronized List such as the Lists and other collections provided by Fujaba libraries) while you're traversing it by it's index. I suggest you to make a clone of the List first (clone, not referencing the List again), traverse the clone, use the modulo operator as suggested by Darshan, and remove the values from your original List.